# C++ and java , SQLITE server access same Time

Tags: java, c++, sqlite, interop, server

I have a problem, I need to create a dll for software un c++, this dll need to communicate with SQLITE. But at the same time I have Java application who need to communicate to the database too.

So I need to create a server for taking the request from both application (c++ and java) and launch them to SQLITE.
But in which language I can Create this server and with which API I can communicate to this server with my two application.

I need it, because the c++ and java application are one all computer on the network and they edit the same database.

And I choose SQLite because I think it's the more efficiency for my solution, because we don't want to put a lot of software on computer.

Comment: Two different applications can use the same sqlite database at the same time, though only one of them can write at the same time (the other is blocked). Why do you want to create a server for this?

Comment: if he is blocked, did he wait or stop ? because someone said me to create a server because of this .

Comment: From site SQLlite : "http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html
the part of : Client/Server Applications, or i don't understand well the text.

Comment: It waits. That what they mean when they say "writers queue up". And "client/server" means - communicating with the database over a network, not on the same computer.

Comment: yes but both application are on many computer and we have one server for database. that the probleme ( i edit my post for add it)

Comment: In that case sqlite is not a good solution. You are supposed to install a good client/server based database on the server (mysql/postgresql/Oracle/MSSQL/etc.) and all the client machines should work with that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the server in whichever language you wish as long as you send and receive messages over sockets, as bytes, which aren't language specific and easy to implement. This way you can also do an easy switch to a distributed application. If the server and the clients are on the same machine, just assign them different ports.

It's a difficult question to answer because the way you worded it, it seems you want both architectural and implementation solutions, the first of which is, up to a point, subjective, and the latter quite complex. For helpful Java libraries look into Java RMI and CORBA. Perhaps someone else knows a better and easier way of doing it though, this is the first thing that came to mind.

Another way to do it would be to have each client deal with their own access directly to the database since SQLite is its own thing, allowing both C++ and Java to use it. I'm not sure, however, how difficult it might be to deal with locking the db file from being accessed by several clients at the same time.

Comment: Thanks,  The probleme with SQLite is we can't acces at the same time to the data with 2users... that why i need to create a server....
For "architectural and implementation solutions" its could be good but i don't dream :p
i will look for RMI and corba :p and wait for other reply :p

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have support for multiple users, setting user access rights, or anything along these lines. You could definitely implement a 'server' based wrapper to manage users but this just seems quite tedious to me. I would recommend switching to MySQL as it has user management features already built in that may help with your problem.

Comment: It's for professional computer and the i dont really like to install an other software during the installation of the java application... and don't really know to do it proprely.

Comment: Where in the question did you see anything about users?

Comment: Two programs are not the same as two users. Users are identified by credentials and have access to certain databases and schemas. Two applications can use the same user and access the same database and schemas. That means the database supports multiple access, even if it doesn't support users and authentication.

Comment: But he is saying they both edit the database.. so I'm leaning toward MySQL.

Comment: Well, I'm leaning towards MySQL/PostgreSQL as well, but not because of multi *users*, but because SQLite is *not* a client-server database.